# Voronoi not plotting real time data tuple index out of range

Tags: python, tuples, voronoi, index-error

I'm trying to plot a voronoi diagram with real time data, but get the error:

```python
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

the code:

```python
data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes

data = str(data, "utf-8") #convert bytes into string and fix the 'b'
#data.decode("utf-8", errors="ignore")

data = data.strip(" ").split(".")

x = data[0]
y = data[1]
x = float(x.replace( ',', '.'))
y = float(y.replace( ',', '.'))
vor = Voronoi(x,y)
```

[image: code and error]

The value of the `data` variable is like this: `[b' 0,2036377.2,04291.', b' 0,2027879.2,040747.']`.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: can you please include an example of the data you're trying to parse as the problem can be due to wrong parsing of the data?

Comment: also, you don't seem to be using the `Voronoi` class properly as `npoints` is expected to be an array and you are passing a float (i.e. `x`) which leads to `y` being used as `furthest_site ` argument. please read the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Voronoi.html) first

Comment: example of the data: 
(0.4175202, 1.514597)
(0.411608, 1.510047)
(0.4102539, 1.509755)
(0.4093362, 1.510369)

Comment: this works just fine: `python -c "from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d; import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; vor = Voronoi([[0.4175202, 1.514597], [0.411608, 1.510047], [0.4102539, 1.509755], [0.4093362, 1.510369]]); voronoi_plot_2d(vor); plt.show()"`.  As I said, you just need to pass a array, which in this case is a list of list and not a list of tuples

Comment: Thank you, what s the best way to convert the list of tuples into a list of array with this x, y variables?

Comment: in order to convert the your input data to you'll need to do the following: `data =  [(0.4175202, 1.514597) (0.411608, 1.510047) (0.4102539, 1.509755) (0.4093362, 1.510369)]; data = [ [i[0], i[1]] for i in  data]`. Could you please reply with the raw data you get after the command `data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes` as I'll try to fix the question and place an answer that aggregates all the different issues you've experienced with the code above

Comment: The raw data: b' 0,2036377.2,04291.'
b' 0,2027879.2,040747.'
b' 0,2018921.2,037455.'
b' 0,2010467.2,034439.'
b' 0,2004007.2,031721.'
b' 0,1996321.2,027795.'
b' 0,1989551.2,023898.'
b' 0,1983429.2,020666.'
b' 0,1978466.2,017263.'

Comment: When I try data = [ [i[0], i[1]] for i in data], I got the error: TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: that means that you have a structure different from the one I was assuming. I was assuming that your data structure was like this: `data = [(0.4175202, 1.514597), (0.411608, 1.510047), (0.4102539, 1.509755), (0.4093362, 1.510369)]`

Comment: Ok, and how should you go from the raw data:b' 0,2036377.2,04291.' b' 0,2027879.2,040747.' to data = [(0.4175202, 1.514597), (0.411608, 1.510047), (0.4102539, 1.509755), (0.4093362, 1.510369)]. Just try to follow you here

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the error you are getting is because you are passing the wrong input to `Voronoi`, please read the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Voronoi.html)

Regarding what you are trying to do and assuming that the `data` you get from `data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)` is like this `[b' 0,2036377.2,04291.', b' 0,2027879.2,040747.']` you then have to do address the following points:

- decode the bytes to string
- extract the coordinates using for example a regular expression
- convert the string representation of the coordinates to `float`
- organise the data structure to create a `Voronoi` diagram

The code you have so far address most of these points but it does not structure the data as the input for the `Voronoi` diagram.

The code bellow addressed all the points and will create the `Voronoi` diagram for you:

```python
import re
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import doctest
doctest.testmod()  # used to test the docstring 

# compile the regular expression used to parse the input data
regex = re.compile(' (\d+,\d+)\.(\d+,\d+)\.')

def parse_data(data):
    """
    parse a list of strings with x, y coordinates

    >>> data = [b' 0,2036377.2,04291.', b' 0,2027879.2,040747.']
    >>> parse_data(data)
    [[0.2036377, 2.04291], [0.2027879, 2.040747]]
    """
    proc_data = []
    for i in data:
        m = regex.match(i.decode('utf-8')) # decode the bytes and match the regex
        if m:
            # parse the coordinates and organise the data structure
            proc_data += [[float(m.group(1).replace(',','.')),
                           float(m.group(2).replace(',','.'))]]
    return proc_data

data = [b' 0,2036377.2,04291.', b' 0,2027879.2,040747.', 
        b' 0,2018921.2,037455.', b' 0,2010467.2,034439.', 
        b' 0,2004007.2,031721.', b' 0,1996321.2,027795.',
        b' 0,1989551.2,023898.', b' 0,1983429.2,020666.',
        b' 0,1978466.2,017263.']

data = parse_data(data)
vor = Voronoi(data)  # create the Voronoi diagram with correct input data
voronoi_plot_2d(vor)
plt.show()
```

The result is the following:
[image: Imgur]

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation and code. When I run this in a script apart it all works fine. But when Implement this in my real time incoming bytes script I got some errors: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'decode'. So maybe the problem here is that the data in your code have an end point and the incoming bytes do not because they are in a while True loop. What do you think about this error and how would you solve this?

Comment: the error means that at some point the data you´re getting from the `sock.recvfrom(1024)` is an `int`. One way to overcome this, is to use `try/except` (see doc [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)) and catch any exception you are expecting, in this case the fact that data is not in the format you expect it to be.